# When is it appropriate to break subject and verb agreement, conjugating the verb as singular when the subject is plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I have seen this phenomenon happen in several Youtube videos about aviation crashes in the channel Mentour Pilot. For instance, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhO-87wwLJs&t=1106s) (timestamp 18:26):

> A hundred and one passengers and crew perish in this accident but
> miraculously **65 people survives**. When **the pieces comes** to a complete stop, the survivers manage to get outside [...]"

Note the "s" in survives, as though the subject was singular (1 person) instead of plural (65 people). Inmediately after, the same thing happens again with the plural "the pieces" and the singular verb "comes". The fact that this has happened accross many videos in that series as well as the series itself being very informative and having high production standards makes me think that these are not mistakes but are some kind of deliberate device. Is that so?

In what kind of circumstances is it appropriate to break the subject/verb agreement in such ways?

Comment: In general, it's not appropriate. Those sentences look like they were either mistranscribed or spoken by a non-native speaker. Don't forget that there are no grammar rules on Utube.

Comment: I encourage you to have a look to the linked video, I am pretty sure this is what the person in the video says, so definitely not a mistranscription. It is true that the speaker is not a native speaker, according to a wiki I consulted he is a Swede.

Comment: Just a mistake by the speaker. Only plural agreement is correct.

Comment: Native or not doesn't matter, "Someone once said it this way" is not a model for written English. You're right that it's not a transcription error.

Comment: Those are just non-native errors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about English but someone who is clearly a non-native speaker.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Alright, but it's not that someone *once* said it this way. It was a recurrent thing and I finally felt compelled to ask after hearing it many times.

Comment: @Lambie check out the accepted answer. Native speakers do also make this kind of mistake sometimes.

Comment: @jarmanso7 These are **unlikely** native speaker errors. Very unliikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mentour Pilot is from rural Sweden, as [his About page explains](https://mentourpilot.com/about/). He speaks with a very noticeable accent; I'm assuming he isn't a native English speaker. This likely explains why his grammar and pronunciation sometimes seem incorrect to us.

It is likely relevant that, as [Wikipedia explains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_grammar), in his native Swedish verbs are not inflected for person or number.

Comment: "This likely explains why his **grammar and pronunciation** sometimes **seems** incorrect to us". Is this a pun?

Comment: No, just a typo. Edited. Though this does demonstrate that native speakers often make the same mistake!